# SQL Server script for adding to a list field, and including commas in the text

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

We have some autogenerated SQL structures in SQL Server Management Studio 19.1.56.0, one which has a field like this:

> Property description As **list** Of %Library.String(COLLATION = "EXACT",
> MAXLEN = 255, TRUNCATE = 0) [ SqlColumnNumber = 14, SqlFieldName =
> html, SqlListType = SUBNODE ];

We have been trying to UPDATE this field for a particular entry, by adding more elements to the "list". We get the entry something like this

```
SELECT * FROM EQA.EQA_PAGE_VERSION where IEN = '21'
```

But when we update, something like:

```
UPDATE EQA.EQA_PAGE_VERSION   
SET description = CONCAT(description, 'goodbye')   
WHERE IEN = 21;
```

### we keep running into the MAXLEN string length, when the "description" becomes more than 255 characters. Clearly we need to augment the "list", not just add to the particular string in the list. How do we do that for that particular element?

Update: I see that the "list" is apparently comma-delimited, so that if you put in a comma it adds a new list element:

> UPDATE EQA.EQA_PAGE_VERSION
> SET description = CAST(description AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + ',New string to add'
> WHERE IEN = '12';

works. However, there is a new issue: I don't see how to escape commas to include them in the text. No matter what I do with quotes or , the parser seems to turn each comma in the input string into a delimiter.
How can I get commas to be part of the text, instead?

Comment: why not increase the size of the database column

Comment: It is autogenerated, not under our control. We can increase it temporarily but it will get overwritten the next time the SQL structure is autogenerated. It needs to be unlimited in size, which is why the generator made it a list.

Comment: then tell the auto generator ou want more space, what creates the database?

Comment: Intersystems Cache' Fileman to SQL converter. It is mirroring the setup of a Word Processing field in Fileman, which is a sequential stack of global nodes each of which is limited to 255 characters.

Comment: https://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GSTU_convert#GSTU_convert_fileman

Comment: then yyou should ask if some one knows how to  circumvent those limits, sql can alter the field, but then you need to do it after ever migration

Comment: if it's recreated from somewhere, why do you update it? won't that be lost too?

Comment: The data dictionaries of the Fileman fields get changed as people work on the system over there. Then we need to re-synch to have SQL access. It happens often.

Comment: We're not trying to alter the field, just be able to file into it, adding new members to the list. We have Write privileges on the linked database.

Comment: We have talked to Intersystems about messing with the FM2SQL converter wizard; they don't plan to fix it anytime soon.